# Dividir una imagen en 3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, imagen

estoy tratando de dividir una imagen en tres columnas iguales con Javascript pero no se como generar las 3 imágenes y que queden guardadas en el mismo directorio en el que está la original, alguna idea o manual para hacerlo, solo consigo ver ejemplos de rompecabezas y no se muy bien como adaptarlo, muchas gracias:)

Comment: ¿Pero lo que quieres es generar 3 ficheros con las partes de la imagen o simplemente mostrarla dividida en 3?

Comment: Hola Silvia, ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? (añade código y los errores/dificultades que te estés encontrando) ¿Está esta pregunta relacionada con [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/141897/250) que hiciste para algo parecido en phonegap? Si es así, sería importante indicarlo.

Comment: Si, tiene relación con esa pregunta ya que no sabia como podía hacer peticiones a Java ya que tengo este código en Java, y creo que ya encontré la manera de utilizar Java con Phonegap, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que para esto yo usaría java, c#, php, nodejs..... 
Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo vía javascript te dejo un enlace
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463416/split-base64-image-into-parts

Pero tienes que transformarlas en base64. Lo malo que no puedes guardarlas, tendrías que descargarlas. Con javascript no puedes escribir en la máquina que lo ejecuta (por seguridad..)

Si te gusta mucho javascript, prueba NodeJs y esta librería para trabajar con las imágenes.

https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp

Saludos.

Comment: Sí, utilice Java para esto, pero tenía problemas para utilizar código Java desde PhoneGap por lo que me puse a investigar si podía hacerlo con Javascript, muchas gracias por la ayuda